# Data from Mysql to Bigquery via Cloud data fusion(query with multiple joins)

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a complex query to run in MySQL with multiple table joins and bring that output data into BigQuery table.

I want to use cloud data fusion for this. I'm new to GCP and not sure how to achieve this.

I know that MySQL tables can be brought into BigQuery tables using data fusion but that is a direct pull. what if I want to run a query with multiple table joins and bring that data to BigQuery using cloud data fusion ?

Is it possible , if so, can you please let me know how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, Mysql source plugin lets you write a SQL, so you can join the tables there. However if the tables that you want to join are in different databases, then you can have multiple Mysql sources and join the data on Data Fusion with using Joiner plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the response @MeteHan .. Will try on it